# Как оформляется цитата и авторский текст в одном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

*Однажды он сказал: «Придет день, когда вы все глубоко пожалеете о своем выборе», и этот день действительно настал.*

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это цитирование **по образцу прямой речи**, поэтом все **правила сохраняются:** *Однажды он сказал: «Придет день, когда вы все глубоко пожалеете о своем выборе», и этот день действительно настал.* http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=163#pp163

Пример: *Ко мне подходит Борис, говорит: «Хорошо сбил, замечательно», но глаза его блестят, полные зависти* (Куд.) — запятая разделяет части сложносочиненного предложения, связанные противительным союзом но; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ с ссылками.