# А может двоеточие относиться не ко всей оставшейся фразе?

Tags: синтаксис, двоеточие

Прочитал в книжке именно такую фразу, где оно относится только к одному слову, а конец предложения уже отдельно:

*Найдя ответ, она твёрдо сама себе ответила: «Сумасшедшая!» и пошла дальше.*

Так можно писать? Я думал, что нет.

Answer (score 3):

**Найдя ответ, она твёрдо сама себе ответила: «Сумасшедшая!» — и пошла дальше.**

В вашем случае должно действовать [следующее правило (п. 2)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159):

> Если прямая речь находится внутри слов автора, то перед ней ставится
> двоеточие, а после нее — или запятая, или тире, или запятая и тире (по
> условиям контекста):
> *…Она сказала: «Нынче, говорят, в университете уже мало занимаются
> науками» — и подозвала свою собачку Сюзетку* (Л. Т.) — тире перед
> союзом и при однородных сказуемых.

Comment: А как выдумаете, почему запятая имеет значение?

Comment: @Sharon запятая имеет значение потому, что она разделяет части ССП. А вот тире в случае, когда идут однородные члены, кажется мне довольно формальным.

Comment: Наверное, паузу обозначает, а в случае с запятой паузы нет. Кстати, там любая запятая полходит: бессоюзная  связь для однородных членов, деепричастный оборот.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Артем, есть еще один вариант оформления предложения без тире: "Найдя ответ, она твёрдо сама себе ответила «Сумасшедшая!» и пошла дальше.

Надо только убрать двоеточие, и прямая речь будет членом предложения.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Я и сам как раз так и хотел оформить: убрать двоеточие!

Comment: Я думал о таком оформлении, но не понял, какими правилами оно регламентируется. И надо ли в таком случае писать слово в кавычках с заглавной буквы.

Comment: Это есть у Розенталя, надо только найти где. Я позже поищу ссылку. А в примерах оба варианта используются.

Comment: Здесь имеется, по выражению Розенталя, "глагол речи-мысли" "ответила", так что двоеточие кажется обязательным. Но буду заинтересован, если найдёте пример и тем более правило, что прямая речь в данном случае может быть членом предложения.

Comment: Завтра – непременно найду. У Розенталя материал разбросан по разным темам, что не есть хорошо и удобно.

Comment: Только не забывайте, пожалуйста, про упоминание через @. Это ваш ответ, и мне не приходят уведомления из-под него без упоминания.

Comment: Мне этот вариант (без двоеточия) кажется странным. Тоже хотелось бы взглянуть на правило.

Comment: @oleedd
Сказала же, завтра. Или ко мне зайдите, там вроде бы есть примеры. https://proza.ru/2021/02/23/1551 Раздел 5, тема 4.

Comment: А мне странной кажется привычка после таких глаголов **всегда** ставить двоеточие. Ни в коем случае никого обидеть не хочу!

Comment: Да хоть и послезавтра. Просто к слову было сказано. Странным кажется, потому что такое используется при родовом слове: *Она твёрдо сама себе сказала фразу «Я сумасшедшая!» и пошла дальше.*

Comment: @oleedd Это кому что кажется странным. Не забывайте, то двоеточие в устной речи  соотсветствует интонационному предупреждению. которого здесь нет.

Comment: Вы уверены, что всегда интонационное предупреждение? Вроде бы при прямой речи двоеточие больше формальность. Формальность — это не всегда плохо.

Comment: У вас там есть пример: "Ещё раз повторив «Через час!» –  он направился было к дверям", но он неверен: в изданиях там стоит двоеточие перед кавычками.

Answer (score 1):

На этот вопрос в одной из моих тем был получен ответ от **[Sharon](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/180132/sharon)**: https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/470304/200257

> Это цитирование по образцу прямой речи, поэтом все правила
> сохраняются: Однажды он сказал: «Придет день, когда вы все глубоко
> пожалеете о своем выборе», и этот день действительно настал.
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=163#pp163
>
> Пример: Ко мне подходит Борис, говорит: «Хорошо сбил, замечательно»,
> но глаза его блестят, полные зависти (Куд.) — запятая разделяет части
> сложносочиненного предложения, связанные противительным союзом но;
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159

Comment: Нет, здесь иная ситуация. В вашем случае по контексту после прямой речи стоит запятая. Если же запятой нет, то должно стоять тире.

Comment: Здесь нет запятой после прямой речи, посмотрите п.2 этого правила: Она сказала: «Нынче, говорят, в университете уже мало занимаются науками» — и подозвала свою собачку Сюзетку http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159

Comment: @Theej  Кстати, это не цитирование, а "натуральная" прямая речь., так как это  речь персонажа.. А цитируют обычно писателей, какие-то их высказывания.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!